# Middleware / interserver communication tool

Tags: software-development, networking, sql

I'm looking for an engine to store key / value pairs to transfer data between servers.

The goal is to have a server write these values to the database and then not be able to retrieve them. Another server (with another set of credentials) can then come in and read these key / value pairs back. Preferably after a read has succeeded it would immediately remove the value. The only item I'm even slightly familiar with would be redis, but I'm not sure it fits the bill.

What are my options?

Comment: A normal database server with two stored procedures (with appropriate permissions each) reading/writing to a shared table may be all you need.